# How to edit Variable Fillet with SolidWorks API

Tags: vb.net, solidworks, solidworksapi

I'm wondering how I go about editing a Variable fillet using the solidworks API.
In short, I'm updating a multi-body part which contains several variable fillets that break when a base feature is updated. (The edge is no longer present and goes missing in the feature)

This is the code that I have:

```
Dim swSelMgr As SelectionMgr = swModel.SelectionManager

Dim status = swModel.Extension.SelectByID2(featureName, "BODYFEATURE", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)

Dim swFeat As Feature = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObject6(1, -1)
Dim featData As VariableFilletFeatureData2 = swFeat.GetDefinition
swModel.ClearSelection2(True)

Dim startVert As Vertex = filletEdge.GetStartVertex()
Dim endVert As Vertex = filletEdge.GetEndVertex()
Dim R1 = radii(0)
Dim R2 = radii(1)

status = featData.AccessSelections(swModel, Nothing)

featData.AsymmetricFillet = False
featData.ConicTypeForCrossSectionProfile = swFeatureFilletProfileType_e.swFeatureFilletCircular
featData.SetConicRhoOrRadius(filletEdge, R1)
featData.SetRadius(startVert, R2)
featData.SetRadius(endVert, R1)

Try
    status = swFeat.ModifyDefinition(featData, swModel, Nothing)
Catch ex As Exception
    status = False
End Try
```

Yet the final status returns False. radii(0) is 0.00314 and radii(1) is 0.00164. I can put everything in manually via the UI and it applies just fine. I've never worked with variable fillets through the API so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing, just taking shots in the dark. I do know that its a symmetric fillet, with a circular profile. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is a syntax error if I am not mistaken "Dim R1 = radii(0) Dim R2 = radii(1)". This is incorrect call "ModifyDefinition(featData, swModel, Nothing)", first argument is okay, second argument is an **assembly IModelDoc2** document, and third argument is the **Component2 object** that you can try to get by setting your swFeat as **Entity** then use **GetComponent** member to get the last argument.

Comment: @MarioMalic I should have mentioned that this code snippet is inside its own function and radii is an parameter to that function, as an array of doubles.  This is not a syntax error.

Comment: @MarioMalic How I have done the ModifyDefinition is correct,  The first argument is OK, but the second, if not working in assembly mode (which I am not), would be the ModelDoc2 object and the 3rd is Nothing.  If I was working within the context of the assembly, then how you worded it would be correct.  I'm working within the context of the part

Comment: Apologies, I didn't notice this is VB.net.

Comment: If you upload an example file for your case, I would try to figure out the solution.